# express js server dosn't allow post from deployed app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have problem with the server when deploy my app with gh-pages. When i try to POST on /contact url it respond 405 Method Not Allowed.
I tried with cors on express but it's same. My client side is with React.
When I run it on localhost everything work normal but in production like server doesn't exist. Should I add something in my react app to connect them or...?

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors')
const pass = require('./.vscode/settings.json')
const config = require('./config')

var allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3000','https://some.github.io'];

const corsOptions = {
  origin: function(origin, callback){    
    if(!origin) return callback(null, true);    
    if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1){
      var msg = 'The CORS policy for this site does not ' +
                'allow access from the specified Origin.';
      return callback(new Error(msg), false);
    }   
    return callback(null, true);
  },
  credentials: true,
}

const app = express();
const route = express.Router();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client' ,'/public')))
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://some.github.io');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use('/', route)

http.createServer(app).listen(config.port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${config.port}`)
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('server')
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client' ,'/public', 'index.html'));
});

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  port: 465,              
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  auth: {
    user: 'email',
    pass: pass,
  },
  secure: true,
});

route.get('/contact', (req,res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Contact page')
})

route.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
  const {name, email, message} = req.body
  console.log(req.body)
  const mailToMe = {
    from: 'email',  // sender address
    to: 'email',   // list of receivers
    subject: name,
    text: message,
    html: message + `<br> From: ${email}`,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailToMe, (error, info) => {
    if(error) {
      return console.log(error)
    }

    res.redirect('/contact')
    res.status(200)
  });

})
```

That is the client side component in react:

```
const ContactForm = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
    const [errorName, setErrorName] = useState('')
    const [errorEmail, setErrorEmail] = useState('')
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')
    const [isSubmited, setIsSubmited] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        if(isSubmited){
            setTimeout(() => {
                setIsSubmited(false)
            }, 7000)
        }
    })

    const handelValidation = () => {
        setErrorName('')
        setErrorEmail('')
        setErrorMessage('')
        // Name
        if (!name) {
            setErrorName("Name field cannot be empty!")
            return false
        }

        if (!name.match(/[A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+/)) {
            setErrorName("Тhe first and second names must begin with a capital letter and continue with lowercase letters!")
            return false
        }

        // Email
        if (email === '') {
            setErrorEmail("Email field cannot be empty!")
            return false
        }

        if (!email.match(/[A-Za-z0-9.]+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+.?[a-z]+/)) {
            setErrorEmail("Email must be valid!")
            return false
        }

        // Message
        if (message === '') {
            setErrorMessage("Message field cannot be empty!")
            return false
        }
        
        if(message.length <= 10) {
            setErrorMessage("Message should more the 10 characters!")
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let result = handelValidation();
        console.log(name, email, message)

        if (!result) {
            return
        }

        let data = { name: name, email: email, message: message }

        axios.post(`/contact`, data).catch(e => console.log(e))

        setName('')
        setEmail('')
        setMessage('')

        setIsSubmited(true)
    }

    return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Input
                onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                label={"What is your name?"}
                name={"name"}
                icon={"far fa-user"}
                placeholder={"Type your first and second name..."}
                value={name}
                isError={errorName}
            />
            {errorName ? <Notification error={errorName} /> : ""}
            <Input
                onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                label={"Write your email"}
                name={"email"}
                icon={"far fa-envelope"}
                placeholder={"Type your email..."}
                value={email}
                isError={errorEmail}
            />
            {errorEmail ? <Notification error={errorEmail} /> : ""}
            <Input
                onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}
                label={"What is your message to me?"}
                name={"message"}
                icon={"far fa-comment-alt"}
                placeholder={"Type your message..."}
                value={message}
                isError={errorMessage}
            />
            {errorMessage ? <Notification error={errorMessage} /> : ""}
            <SubmitButton title={"Submit form"} />
            {isSubmited ? <Div>Thank you for contacting me! You must have received an automatic reply 
                to the email you entered above.</Div> : ""}
        </Form>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you show your client-side code that tries to post to your express app?

Comment: Is request working on Postman?

Comment: The client is at gh-pages but where is your server hosted ?

Comment: ouu should I host the server to? Sorry it's my first time with deployment and everything is new to me in there :(

Comment: You don't do request to localhost from github, do you?

Comment: no, the request are to the hosted app, I was thinking that the server is hosted there too, so I should host my server somewhere too and then request to that domain?

Answer (score 0):

Github Pages does not support any kind of server-side programming.

You need hosting (there are many cloud services that will let you deploy a Node.js web service to them as well as VPSs and dedicated servers you can rent) on which you can run your server-side JavaScript. You can't just drop it onto Github pages and have it do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy public server instead of local server. Local servers are accessible for only you, not the others.